# How to translate text string in config file, it throw exception during runtime

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Is possible to translate strings in configuration files?

I'm trying to use trans() and __(), but it doesn't work.

It throws BindingResolutionException Target class [translator] does not exist.

I guess it the translator class didn't load before the config file load. Any idea how to fix it.

My config file:

```
'authentication_column' => 'email', 
'authentication_column_name' => __('backpack::base.email_address'),
```

Inside the file /resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/auth/login.blade.php

```
<label class="control-label" for="{{ $username }}">{{ config('backpack.base.authentication_column_name') }}</label>
```

Now my solution is edit the login.blade.php
to

```
<label class="control-label" for="{{ $username }}">{{ trans('backpack::base.email_address') }}</label>
```

Comment: You can’t. What is it you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated in the questions, I want to show the field name as translate version

Comment: unless you want to set these configuration values from a service providers boot method, your solution is the way to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Loading configuration is done before registering providers in which the 'translator' class is being bound.
It's reasonable as config values are required for instantiating classes during the boot,
So translating functionality is not available in config files.